# is there a way to avoid form events in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I've recently been learning vb.net, coming from a background in java and c. I'm pretty comfortable adding buttons and things like that to my form, and then using those click events to call functions in other classes.

However, the way I have been testing my code is to add a button to my form and then have the click event initiate the first function call (basically I have this button acting like a java main() method.

I have recently been wondering if there is a more efficient way of testing out my code that is similar to how it is done in java or c. By this I mean, is there a way to skip all of the form stuff and just have a sub procedure or function that is similar to a main method in java?

I've seen several answers that have mentioned how to add get a main sub to work in vb.net, but they required changing some of the properties of the project. I'm looking for something I can just code and hit run without having to disable the application framework.

Since I'm still relatively new to vb.net, I am also wondering if this is they wrong way to go about it? If I was being asked to create some code in an interview or something, would I need to worry about launching everything, or would they just want to see me implement the class as a standalone file?

Thank you for any advice you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always start a "Console Application" project type instead of a "Windows Forms Application Project"

This skips all of the nice GUI Forms and gives you a Main() all ready to go.  You can write to the screen using

```
Console.WriteLine(string)
```

and then pause execution at the end by using

```
Console.ReadLine
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically call this....

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    If Me.IsPostBack Then
        'Do some stuff here if a form has been submitted, button, etc.
    Else
        'This is the first time this page has been called, so setup drop-downs, etc. here
    End If

End Sub
```

So basically this is the first thing that gets called.  If I'm testing, I can default certain things in the first part of the If....but again...may not be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried doing something similar to this with the onLoad event but for some reason it wasn't working correctly.